# As a system of linear equations show lines of action of 3 co-planar forces in equilibrium meet at a point.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics

I have multiple ways of showing that the lines of action of 3 co-planar forces in static equilibrium meet at a point.  But they combine physical arguments and math.  It seems like there should be some purely mathematical way of proving the claim, treating it as a system of equations having a unique solution.

Is there a way to express this as a uniquely determined system of linear equations?

Here are the equations of equilibrium corresponding to the illustration, where $\vec{r}_1=\mathfrak{p}_1-\mathscr{O},$ etc.  The heavy gray line is a  rigid rod in equilibrium under the applied forces.

$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{0}&=\vec{f}_{1}+\vec{f}_{2}+\vec{f}_{3}\\
\vec{0}&=\vec{r}_{1}\times\vec{f}_{1}+\vec{r}_{2}\times\vec{f}_{2}+\vec{r}_{3}\times\vec{f}_{3}\\
\vec{0}&=\left(\vec{r}_{1}-\vec{p}\right)\times\vec{f}_{1}+\left(\vec{r}_{2}-\vec{p}\right)\times\vec{f}_{2}+\left(\vec{r}_{3}-\vec{p}\right)\times\vec{f}_{3}
\end{aligned}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a line through $r_i$ in the direction $f_i$ is $(r-r_i)\times f_i=0$ which we can rewrite as $r\times f_i=r_i\times f_i$. Now assuming $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not parallel, they intersect at some point $p$, so
$$p\times f_1=r_1\times f_1$$
and $$p\times f_2=r_2\times f_2$$
which gives that

$$p\times(f_1+f_2)=r_1\times f_1+r_2\times f_2.$$
Now add $p\times f_3$ to both sides, to give
$$0=r_1\times f_1+r_2\times f_2+p\times f_3$$
by the fact that the forces are in equilibrium (your first equation). But using the fact that the moments are in equilibrium (your second equation) gives that
$$r_1\times f_1+r_2\times f_2+r_3\times f_3=r_1\times f_1+r_2\times f_2+p\times f_3$$
so $$r_3\times f_3=p\times f_3$$
which exactly says that $p$ (the intersection of the first two lines) also lies on the third line, thus the lines all intersect at a common point.

Comment: When I asked a physicist about the case of parallel forces, he used the assumption of projective geometry that parallel lines meet at a point at infinity.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Yes, if you allow the point at infinity, then your claim is also true in the cases with two or three of the forces being parallel.

Comment: A moment's reflection will convince you that if any two of the forces are parallel, all three must be.

Comment: The hook I was missing was the equation of a line in the form $(r-r_i)\times f_i=0$.  I'm certain I've encountered it before, but its practical utility was lost on me until now.